# How to set page size for records in Netsuite using RESTlet?

Tags: netsuite

I am getting records min and max 1000 records at a time. if i am keeping this way to fetch record , My program takes long time to retrieve. And also i don't need 1000 records in certain situation.

I have already tried in this way .

```
Setup -> Integration -> Web Services Preferences
```

Are there any other alternate possibilities to mention the page size in GUI mode or RESTlet [like in filter or search] ?

Comment: are you using a saved search to fetch records?

Comment: no. i am getting record by this  nlapiSearchRecord(datain.recordtype, null, filters, new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid').setSort())

Comment: Please use nlapiCreateSearch, see my answer for the example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup -> Integration -> Web Services Preferences ,has nothing to do with the search result size

You can use `nlapiCreateSearch()` to limit search results

```
var search = nlapiCreateSearch(RECORD_TYPE, FILTERS, COLUMNS);
var results = search.runSearch();
var records = results.getResults(0, (MAX < 1000?  MAX: 1000) );
```

Comment: U r Great..  Thanks lot Prasun.